# hide all elements wit specific alt value

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to hide all elements which have an ALT value of `3` using jquery.

hide all elements with attribute  `alt="3"`

Is this possible? And if so, how can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('[alt="3"]').hide();
```

It uses the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to match elements where `alt` has a value of `3`.

`hide()`, obviously, hides all matched elements. To narrow the selector down (and make it a bit faster), you can always add the tag name as usual:

```
$('div[alt="3"]').hide();
```

---

For dynamic values, you can use ordinary string concatenation:

```
var theValue = 3;

$('div[alt="' + theValue + '"]').hide();
```

Comment: and if i want to put a javascript variable as the 3 ?